# Is this a view model?

Tags: mvvm

I'm still new to MVVM and am trying to understand the concepts.

I have a class generated by Linq To Sql for a table.

I want this class to look different, so I create a new class with some of the properties from the generated class and a few new properties, that is only dependent on generated class.

Is this class a model, a view model or something different?

Answer (score 2):

`ViewModel` represents the state and behavior of the View. I would call a class a `ViewModel` if:

- It provides property change notification through `INotifyPropertyChanged`
- Has commands for the view
- Provies a model for the view, by specializing the model for easier data binding (formatting etc)

Comment: Should I insert && or || between the bullets?

Comment: ||, but most view models do all of these as the code progresses.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a View Model, but not necessarily. Are these extra properties there for the purpose of supporting a view.  If yes, then you could argue that it's a view model class.

View Models exist because views exist.  Models exist because you have a domain of data. the View Model greases the skids between reality (model) and a given users perception of that reality (the view)